# Common practice to compress image before sending to mobile device？

Tags: php, android, image, file-transfer

My application requires downloading many images from server(each image about 10kb large). And I'm simply downloading each of them with independent `AsyncTask` without any optimization.

Now I'm wondering what's the common practice to transfer these images. For example, I'm thinking about saving zipped images at server, then send zipped file for user's mobile to unzip. In this case, is it better to combine the zip files into one big zip file for user to download?

Or there's better solution? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

It seems combining zip files is a good idea, but I feel it may take too long for user to wait downloading and unzipping all images. So I may put ten or twenty images in each zip file, so user can see some downloaded ones while waiting for more to come. Having multiple `AsyncTask` fired together can be faster right? But they won't finish at the same time even given same file size and same address to download?

Answer (score 1):

Since latency is often the largest problem with mobile connections, reducing the number of connections you have to open is a great way to optimize the loading times. Sending a zip file with all the images sounds like a very good idea, and is probably worth the time implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Images probably are already compressed (gif, jpg, png). You will not reduce filesize but will reduce the number of connections. Which is a good idea for mobile. If it is always the same set of images you can use some sprite technology (sending one bigger image file containing all the images but with different x/y offset, in html you can use the backround with an offset to show the right image).

Comment: thank you! but I'm afraid the images gets uploaded or modified by user all the time..

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the sidebar and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585025/image-size-best-practices-for-mobile-application) topic, but you're asking about patching when I saw the comments.

The best way to make sure is that the user knows what to do with it. You want the user to download X file and have Y output for a different purpose. On the other hand, it appears common practice is that chunks of resources for those not native to the Android app and not able to fit in the APK.

A comparable example is the JDIC apps, which use the popular Japanese resource that are in tandem used for English translations. JDIC apps like WWWJDIC use online downloads for the extremely large reference files that would otherwise have bad latency (which have been mentioned before) on Google servers. It's also bad rep to have >200 MB on Google apps unless it is 3D, which is justifiable. If your images cannot be compressed without extremely long loading times on the app itself, you may need to consider this option. The only downside is to request online connection (also mentioned before).

Also, you could use 7zip and program Android to self-extract it to a location. http://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables

On another note, it would be optimal for the user to perform routine checks on the app while having a one-time download on initial startup. You can then optionally put in an `AsyncTask` so that your files will be downloaded to the app and used after restart or however you want it, so you really need only one `AsyncTask`. The benefit of this is that the user syncs on the apps and he may need to check only once. The downside is that the user may not always be able to update and may need to use 4G or LTE, but that is a minor concern if he can use WiFi whenever he wants.