# Animated gif in Phonegap lags

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm very new to programming and phonegap. The animation of the gifs tested on computer seems to work fine but when exported to api and installed into my phone. The animation is laggy and glitchy. Any idea why this happened? Thank you.

Comment: What's the size of the image?

Comment: They are quite large, ranging from 1.5MB to 3.9MB, there's 6 of them. I uploaded them to website and pulled them from the website.

Comment: Does it render properly via Chrome on the same device? Does it render properly when included with app and loaded from filesystem?

Comment: Even via Chrome , the animation is laggy and glitchy.

Comment: Then the problem does not seem to be related to Phonegap. Your phone's processor might be too weak. You could try to use smaller gifs for testing and expecting to deploy to more powerful devices. Imgur uses videos instead of gifs to display gif animations. Perhaps that concept could be of some use for you to.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for patient and help!

Answer (score 0):

Gifs and Images blow up in size when testing on an emulated or actual phone. Certain mobile's even convert the image to a bitmap which makes the image ridiculously large. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585025/image-size-best-practices-for-mobile-application) covers the issue in better details.

The lag you are experiencing is most likely due to the phone not being strong enough to handle the GIF.

You can try running your app on an emulated phone with a lot of memory and see if the lag persists. Chances are it won't. Then slowly reduce the amount of memory on the phone and watch for the lag to appear.